# Unable to UTF-8 encode JSON response from a url, in an android application

Tags: java, android, json

I have json response from a url like following

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "fav": "",
        "name": "u0637u0627u062cu0646 u0627u0644u062fu062cu0627u062c u0627u0644u0633u0648u064au0633u0631u064a u0627u0644u062bu0627u0646u064a",
        "imageurl": "http://images.media.com/userphotos/250x250/26847.jpg",
        "description": "u0633u062eu0646 u0627u0644u0641u0631u0646 <BR> u0625u0644u0649 350 u062fu0631u062cu0629 u0641u0647u0631u0646u0647u0627u064au062a (175 u062fu0631u062cu0629 u0645u0626u0648u064au0629) . <BR> u062au0631u062au064au0628 u0627u0644u062fu062cu0627u062c u0641u064a u0645u062fu0647u0648u0646 12 u00d7 8 u00d7 2 u0635u062du0646 u0627u0644u062eu0628u0632 . ",
        "details": "<BR> 6 u062cu0644u062f u060c u0627u0644u062bu062fu064a u0627u0644u062fu062cu0627u062c u0627u0644u062eu0627u0644u064au0629 u0645u0646 u0627u0644u0639u0638u0645 <BR> 6 u0634u0631u0627u0626u062d u0627u0644u062cu0628u0646 u0627u0644u0633u0648u064au0633u0631u064a <BR> 1 ( 10.75 u0623u0648u0646u0635u0629 ) u064au0645u0643u0646 u0643u0631u064au0645 u0645u0643u062bu0641 u0645u0646 u062du0633u0627u0621 u0627u0644u062fu062cu0627u062c <BR> 1/4 u0643u0648u0628 u062du0644u064au0628 u0627u0644u0635u0641u062du0629 2 u0643u0648u0628 u0645u0632u064au062c u062du0634u0648 - u0645u062du0646u0643 u0639u0634u0628u0629 <u0631 ",
        "tduration": "1 HR"
    }
]
}
```

In this the name, description and details field contain some language translated content.
I need to encode this into UTF-8 in my android application.
I have used the below code but this doesnot seems working.

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream,"UTF-8"));
```

Anyone having idea about this?

Note : The code is working fine but the characters are not encoded.

Comment: You have **"["** but no **"]"** on your json.

Comment: @BatuhanC Sorry my typing problem. Please check the Edited question.

Comment: a lot of `\ ` seem to be missing from your content.

Comment: `I need to encode this into UTF-8` I don't think this means what you think it means. (encoding is the process of turning a sequence of A (usually humanly readable) into a sequence of B (usually more machine friendly), typically a sequence of characters into a sequence of bytes)

Comment: @njzk2 the content is actually arabic language and i need to dispaly it in my android app.

Comment: @njzk2 is right. And even if you mean converting unicode to readable text that string is not even close to well formed.

Comment: `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes("UTF-8"))))` should do that where str is your jsonString

Comment: The problem comes when am using json.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a json object from the input stream.

```
StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                jsonResults.append(line);
            }
            rd.close();
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());

            boolean result  = jsonObj.getBoolean("someDummyKey");
```

There is also a great library https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http on gitub wich will do all the magic for you. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you text should contain sequences like `\u0637\u0627\u062c\u0646` (note the `\`).

This notation is known as an *Unicode escape syntax*. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html

When used in a String literal, such as `String a = "\u0060";`, this is interpreted by the compiler, and the String `a` contains only 1 character.

When used in a JSON String, it is decoded by the JSON parser. In your case, once the escape sequences are properly fixed, you can simply do:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine() != null) {
    sb.append(line).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
```

In the even that you were not able to fix the escape sequence (for example in the case of a bug on the server side that you are not in a position to have fixed), you could possibly consider doing something like :

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(sb.toString().replace("u06", "\\u06"));
```

Since all your problematic sequences seem to be in the 06 unicode plane (which makes sense, it is where the arabic characters are: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/Character_reference/0000-0FFF )

Comment: as a conclusion, the issue appears to be on the server side, since some other sequence are properly escaped, e.g. `\u003cBR\u003e` which is `<BR>`

Comment: And if you want to display them create a string with the uft-8 encoding using those bytes. Like `String arabic = new String(unicodeString.getBytes("UTF-8"),"UTF-8");`

Comment: @PedroOliveira: the only thing your code extract does is make sure that all the characters in the string *can* be encoded in UTF-8. which is probably the case, since it comes from this `new InputStreamReader(stream,"UTF-8")`

Comment: But AFAIK `sb.toString().replace("u06", "\\u06"))` will make the JSONObject contain unicode chars, instead of arabic. Hence this code to turn them into readable text. I guess. I may be telling a big mistake here :\

Comment: @PedroOliveira `unicode chars, instead of arabic`. There is a misconception here. in unicode, codepoints in the 0600-06ff range are arabic characters. According to json specs, unicode escape sequence can be used in string literals. The replace method I suggest is because the escape sequence appear to be incomplete in the received String.

Comment: Yes I realized that. But since you escaped the sequence with \\ doesn't it means that when you print the result you will not get the Arabic text?

Comment: @PedroOliveira: No, it means that the string will *literally* contain the string `\u06xx`, instead of it being interpreted by the compiler (which would not be possible since this is only for String literals in code that the compiler interprets.). Since the string contains the literal expression of the escape sequence, if you print it, it will print `\u06xx`. But that allows the JSONParser to interpret it, and when you print the content of the String from the JSONObject, you will get arabic characters printed.